# InlineQuery и NextOffset в telegram боте на go

Tags: telegram, golang, inline

Всем привет. Помогите разобраться с проблемой обработки большой пачки результатов (ограничение 50) при инлайн режиме. Нашел параметр NextOffset в InlineConfig, но что то не могу понять как его обработать, все время упираюсь в **Bad Request: too many inline query results specified**

```
func (b *Bot) handleInlineQuery(update tgbotapi.Update) {
    inlineQuery := update.InlineQuery
    offset, _ := strconv.Atoi(inlineQuery.Offset)

    results := make([]interface{}, 0)

    articles, _ := b.db.GetArticlesByTitle(strings.ToLower(inlineQuery.Query))

    for _, article := range articles {
        inlineResult := tgbotapi.NewInlineQueryResultArticle(article.Id(), article.Title, article.Title)
        results = append(results, inlineResult)
    }

    if len(results) < 50 {
        inlineConfig := tgbotapi.InlineConfig{
            InlineQueryID: inlineQuery.ID,
            Results:       results,
            IsPersonal:    true,
            CacheTime: 0,
        }
        _, err := b.api.AnswerInlineQuery(inlineConfig)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    } else {
        inlineConfig := tgbotapi.InlineConfig{
            InlineQueryID: inlineQuery.ID,
            Results:       results,
            IsPersonal:    true,
            CacheTime: 0,
            NextOffset:    strconv.Itoa(offset + 50),
        }
        _, err := b.api.AnswerInlineQuery(inlineConfig)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }
}
```